# upload (send) file in Grails

Tags: java, grails, file-upload, upload

I trying to do the following:

- A user must upload a file to my server
- My server send this file to a openstack Swift backend service

I'm using Grails, any ideas how to do it?

Comment: how do you want to 'send' the file?  Filesystem, rest service, god forbid email :)

Comment: @chrislovecnm - There are worse ways... The file could trigger a printer to print the page, which then would get put into a bottle by a trained monkey, corked, and tossed out to sea. The process would be reversed on the other end. Arguably, email seems like a better choice between the two :)

Comment: @vicoar what type of transport do you want to use?

Comment: I solve it, I just use the Swift Java API: https://github.com/rackspace/java-cloudfiles

Answer (score 0):

I solve it, I use the Swift Java API: https://github.com/rackspace/java-cloudfiles

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the Grails manual - the [section on file uploads](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles) is very well written.

Comment: thanks, but that guide is how to handle an upload (receive and save a file), I wanna send a file

Comment: Sorry - my mistake.  You started with the user uploading a file to your server, so..